# How to get a version of LibreOffice without Unity integration?

Tags: libreoffice

LibreOffice in the latest version of Ubuntu (12.10) is pretty bugged, with several open bugs on things like menus and windows.

How to get a version, even ugly but working, of libreoffice without any unity integration ?

Comment: Do you have a list of said bugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uninstall libreoffice-gtk until https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/1075263 (which is a unity bug and not a libreoffice one btw) is fixed. LibreOffice will be ugly, but the menus will work in the classic way.

Answer (score 1):

You can install LibreOffice from a direct download. Before you do that, remove all other LibreOffice stuff...

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
```

You also probably want to do this, too, before installing

```
sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then, to download the 64 bit version, click [here](http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/3.6.3/deb/x86_64/LibO_3.6.3_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz). Other versions can be found [here](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/).

Navigate to the download directory and unpack the install files (command line will use `tar xfvz`).

Once you have the .deb files (in the folder `DEBS/`), install it with this command

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

You should be good to go! There is another folder in the unpacked folder called "desktop-integration." You can IGNORE this folder.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but you should be able to download it from here: http://www.libreoffice.org/download/

Comment: it would be a better answer if you can explain *how-to* install - and importantly - *how-to-rollback*